# Como retornar manualmente un error 422 en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy validando que todos los campos sean requeridos y que cumplan ciertas condiciones, pero posteriormente necesito que un campo en especifico tenga el mismo valor que otro almacenado en la base de datos.

```
$request->validate([
            'documento' => 'required|numeric|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'fecha_nacimiento' => 'required|date',
            'telefono' => 'required|numeric|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:8',
            'codigo' => 'required|numeric',
        ]);
```

Necesito que el campo codigo tenga el mismo valor que tengo establecido en una tabla de la base de datos.

He realizado algo como esto

```
$codigo = DB::table('parametros')->where('id', 7)->value('valor');

if ($codigo == $request->get('codigo)
{
    ...
}else
{
    return response()->json(['errors' => "Codigo incorrecto",], 422);
}
```

¿Cómo podría hacer la consulta y compararla con el campo? Quiero devolver un error 422 con el campo codigo.

Comment: Puedes usar validador por defecto de laravel para eso 'codigo' => 'exists:parametros', y para devolver el error 422 puedes personalizar el mensaje del validador, o crear uno a medida que devuelva ese error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes crear un Validator vinculado a una consulta a tu base de datos.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'codigo' => [
        'required',
         Rule::exists('parametros')->where(function ($query) {
            return $query->where('id', 7); // Aquí deberás chequear el valor 
        }), 
    ],
]);
```

Luego utilizas el validator en tu `$request->validate`

Puedes consultar la documentación para mas detalle: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#specifying-a-custom-column-name